# Optional chaining causing TypeError

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer

I was surprised by the following behaviour:

```
const a = {};
a?.b.c; // throws TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'c')
```

My intention was to use this expression for when `a` optionally contains `b`, but if `b` is present it is expected to contain `c`. I had expected the expression `a?.b.c` to evaluate to `undefined`, and not throw. What expression should I have used?

I did not use `a?.b?.c` because I wanted it to throw if `b` did not contain `c`.

Comment: `a.b` is also undefined. What about using `a?.b?.c`?

Comment: maybe add another questionmark?

Comment: I did not use `a?.b?.c` because I wanted it to throw if `b` did not contain `c`.

Comment: @James that's not what the operator does. The operator prevents throwing if `b` is undefined, not if `b` doesn't contain `c`

Comment: Not 100% sure what all your requirements are, but for `a.b.c` to give undefined, you could do ->  `(a ?? {}).b.c`

Comment: Optional chaining is for property access. You seem to want it to check the shape of objects and potentially throw an error if it doesn't match. Which it doesn't do. Property access only throws an error if the last thing you tried to access is nullish. Not if the next thing is. Optional chaining, and property access in general, is absolutely the wrong tool for what you expect to happen here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: The code doesn't work as you expected, you will need the following

```
if (a?.b) { // if b does exist (optional)
  const c = a.b.c; // check if c is undefined (compulsary)
}
```

In your code, the null-safe property access/optional chaining prevents the TypeError and returns a null when you try to call "a?.b", the null is then passed to the next property accessor as "(null).c" which throws an error.

You need the question mark on both a and b to avoid the excecption

```
const a = {};
a?.b?.c;
```

Comment: You don't need the `?` in if (a?.b). As a single expression it could be `a.b ?? a.b.c`

Comment: `if (a?.b)` is a false negative for falsy values. E.g., consider `a = { str: "" }` , `b = str`, `c = length`, so `if (a?.str)` would not trigger, yet `a.str.length` is valid thing to reach.

Comment: Also, there is no [null(-ish) coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) in the question. That's `??`. The `?.` is a "null(-ish)-safe property access or "optional chaining".

Comment: Thanks I didn't know it has another name, will edit the post

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the optional chaining operator (**`?.`**) stops the evaluation and returns **`undefined`** as soon as it encounters an undefined or null value in the chain. In your original code **`a?.b.c`**, if **`a`** is undefined, it stops at **`a?.b`** and returns **`undefined`**. However, when you try to access property **`c`** on **`undefined`**, it throws a **`TypeError`**.

You need to handle the scenario where either **`a`** is undefined or **`b`** is undefined, you can achieve this by using conditional statements or a default value. Here are three alternatives:

1. **Using Optional Chaining:**

   ```
   const result = a?.b?.c // undefined
   ```
2. **Using Conditional Statements:**

   ```
   const result = (a && a.b && a.b.c) || undefined;
   ```
3. **Using Default Value + Optional Chaining:**

   ```
   const result = a?.b?.c ?? undefined;
   ```

In all cases, if any part of the chain is undefined, the result will be **`undefined`**. The third approach uses the nullish coalescing operator (**`??`**) to explicitly check for **`null`** or **`undefined`** and provide a default value.